# How to trigger data refresh automatically in R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I have the below function to read data from RDS file.

```
# Function to get updated data
updateData <- function(forceclick = FALSE){

  update_data <<- readRDS(path, "update_data.rds")
  
}
```

And, there is an action button in the UI to update data when it is triggered.

```
##On the UI side action button to refresh data load
actionButton("update_button",
             "Data refresh")

###data refresh code on server side
observeEvent(input$update_button, {

  updateData(forceclick = TRUE)
  
})
```

Here the data is refreshed when the actionButton ´input$update_button´ is triggered.

Here i am supposed to do manual refresh using the action button as shown in the sample code or manually scale down the pods and scale up.

How could the data upload be automated for eg: every morning without the need to trigger the actionButton ´input$update_button´?

Can ´invalidateLater´ be used for observeEvent like below?

```
###data refresh code on server side
  observeEvent(input$update_button, {
    invalidateLater(1000000,session)
    updateData(forceclick = FALSE)
    
  })
```

or could it be solved if the `updateData()` is executed periodically at set time which reads the .rds file?

Comment: You could use [cron](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-cron-to-import-data-daily-and-update-shiny-app/24217/2) to schedule tasks

Comment: I do have a cron job that fetches the updated .RDS files to the PVC storage on the same server which runs the shiny app. However, the shiny application doesn't read the updated data files to the memory from the PVC storage, unless manually triggered.

Comment: I never used something like that so I can't really help you much, but in the link in my comment, they talk about updating some remote storage (a google sheets in their case) and accessing it every time the app launches. I don't know if that could be a solution for you, but you could dig in this way

Comment: ok. i need to find a way. Here i am supposed to do manual refresh using the action button as shown in the sample code or manually scale down the pods and scale up.

Comment: How about use some javascript to click that button for you.  Add this `tags$script('setInterval(function(){$("#update_button").click()}, 24*60*60*1000)')` after the button. It clicks the button every 24 hours.

Comment: [reactiveFileReader()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveFileReader.html) can be used in this scenario. You can create it globally (outside the server function) to share data across sessions.